# PostgreSQL: Update multiple data while using the binding variable

Tags: postgresql, update, patching

I create the new table and insert 10 records into the new table as below:

```sql
userdb=> CREATE TABLE test_tbl(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, STR VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE

userdb=> do $$
begin
for r in 1..10 loop
insert into user1.test_tbl(id, str) values(r, r);
end loop;
end;
$$;
DO
userdb=> select * from test_tbl;
 id | str 
----+-----
  1 | 1
  2 | 2
  3 | 3
  4 | 4
  5 | 5
  6 | 6
  7 | 7
  8 | 8
  9 | 9
 10 | 10
(10 rows)

userdb=> \set id floor(random()*(10-1+1))+1
userdb=> select :id;
 ?column? 
----------
        7
(1 row)

userdb=> select :id;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)

userdb=> select :id;
 ?column? 
----------
        4
(1 row)

userdb=> select :id;
 ?column? 
----------
        7
(1 row)

userdb=> UPDATE test_tbl SET str=111 WHERE ID=:id;
UPDATE 1
userdb=> UPDATE test_tbl SET str=222 WHERE ID=:id;
UPDATE 1
userdb=> UPDATE test_tbl SET str=333 WHERE ID=:id;
UPDATE 2
userdb=> select * from test_tbl;
 id | str 
----+-----
  2 | 2
  4 | 4
  5 | 5
  6 | 6
  7 | 7
  8 | 8
  1 | 111
  3 | 222
  9 | 333
 10 | 333
(10 rows)
```

Anyone could let me know why the last update will update multiple data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is

```
UPDATE test_tbl SET str=333
WHERE ID = floor(random()*(10-1+1))+1;
```

Now `random()` is a volatile function, that is, it can return different results if it is called several times in a single SQL statement. So the expression `floor(random()*(10-1+1))+1` is evaluated *for each row of the table*. As a consequence, it can happen that no row at all or more than one row are found that match the condition.

If you want `random()` to be evaluated only once, the classical trick is to use an uncorrelated subquery, which is evaluated only once:

```
UPDATE test_tbl SET str=333
WHERE ID = (SELECT floor(random()*(10-1+1))+1);
```